Concat multiple joined distinct results
I have a list of orders/containers, then run through multiple operations which also have multiple workstations which have multiple duplicate results
  select top 10000 containername, operationname, txndate, resourcename
  from HistoryMainline hml
  inner join ExecuteTaskHistory th 
    on th.HistoryMainlineId = hml.HistoryMainlineId
  inner join Container c 
    on c.ContainerId = hml.ContainerId
  inner join Operation o
    on o.OperationId = hml.OperationId
  inner join ResourceDef r
    on r.ResourceId = th.WorkstationId

    order by TxnDate desc

Have tried doing select top 1 but that will not provide correct results.
example data:



containername
operationname
resourcename




AF200624-Tag
Crimp_Heatset
CLVE0003


AF200624-Tag
Crimp_Heatset
CLVE0003


AF200624-Tag
Crimp_Heatset
CLVE0003


AF200624-Tag
Crimp_Heatset
CRMP0002



Expected result:



containername
operationname
resourcename




AF200624-Tag
Crimp_Heatset
CLVE0003, CRMP0002




Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Consistent casing of SQL keywords makes SQL much easier to read.

You'll have more luck if you restructure your sql in form of the classic for xml thing: select container, operation, stuff((select distinct ',' + resourcename from whatever for xml path(''), type ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') from MainLine m left join Operation o on o.ID = m.OpID left join Container c ON c.ID = m.CoID

Sorry The data set is very large but basically:
Every transaction has a record in the HistoryMainline table
This links directly to container(order) informatio,.

Sorry The data set is very large but basically:
Every transaction has a record in the HistoryMainline table
This links directly to container(order) information.
Directly to operation
Each Container has  several operation  which have several tasks which could have several workstations

@siggemannen
select ContainerName, OperationName,
stuff((select distinct ',' + resourcename
from historymainline h
inner join container c on c.ContainerId = h.ContainerId
inner join Operation o on o.OperationId = h .OperationId
inner join ExecuteTaskHistory t on t.HistoryMainlineId = h.HistoryMainlineId
inner join ResourceDef r on r.ResourceId = t.WorkstationId
for xml path(''), type ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
from historyMainLine m
left join Operation o on o.OperationName = m.OperationId
left join Container c ON c.ContainerName = m.ContainerId

"the dataset is very large" - that is why you create a [mre] i e. You construct a minimal example dataset to illustrate your issue. You can't clearly describe a dataset in words

And not as images - sample data needs to use table markdown

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Looks to me like you want STRING_AGG(). Your sql will look like: SELECT container, operations, STRING_AGG(resourcename, ',') as resourcename FROM... blah blah blah... GROUP BY container, operations;

@JNevill - tried this but it would return all 4 values as the string - i need only the 2 unique workstations associated with the container at the operation.

Get unique values using STRING_AGG in SQL Server
